# Google Maps - Zoom & Open Specific infoWindow at Launch via URL?

Tags: google-maps, url, infowindow

I have a google maps app using googledocs as its datasource, with 100's of markers.

I'd like to be able zoom in and open the infoWindow for one of these existing makers, at launch from the URL.

The link to this map will originate in another app that will have access to the PKs needed uniquely ID the desired marker.

How would I structure the URL to accomplish this?

Examples??

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_linktomarker.html?marker=1)

Comment: Got this to work using:

function getUrlParams() {
  var params = {};
  window.location.search.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(str,key,value) {
    params[key] = value;
  });
  return params;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this to work using: function getUrlParams() { var params = {}; window.location.search.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(str,key,value) { params[key] = value; }); return params;